# Creating Quantile Cutoffs using SQL Hive

Tags: sql, join, hiveql

I have a table in Hadoop that looks like this (with up to hundreds of columns and millions of rows):

```
+--------+-----------+--------+-----+
| field0 |  field1   | field2 | ... |
+--------+-----------+--------+-----+
| 0.66   | 0.4364153 | 0.31   |     |
| 0.28   | 0.281724  | -1     |     |
| 0.48   | 0.4210872 | 0.58   |     |
| 0.44   | 0.4381265 | 0.59   |     |
| 0.5    | 0.3220857 | 0.65   |     |
| 0.42   | 0.287387  | -1     |     |
| 0.49   | 0.2775216 | -1     |     |
| 0.63   | 0.4347056 | 0.54   |     |
| 0.43   | 0.4501439 | 0.54   |     |
| 0.39   | 0.4312909 | 0.66   |     |
| 0.41   | 0.4432687 | 0.56   |     |
| 0.71   | 0.2678676 | -1     |     |
| 0.43   | 0.270604  | -1     |     |
| 0.51   | 0.2888133 | -1     |     |
| 0.6    | 0.270604  | -1     |     |
| 0.68   | 0.4177005 | 0.67   |     |
| ...    | ...       | ...    | ... |
+--------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

The values inside the fields are always between 0 and 1 (inclusive), -1, or blank (empty string). I want to find the minimum and maximum cutoff points when quantiling the data (with each column quantiled independently). (You can read up on quantiling here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile)

I have a script which generates Hive SQL code like the following (using n=9 as an example). Is there any way to optimize this SQL code so that it does not require so many joins? Each join requires a separate Hadoop MapReduce job (and due to environmental issues, we cannot enable the parallelizable feature which enables multiple SQL jobs to run at once).

```
select
outer0.nonile_field0 as nonile,
outer0.min_field0,
outer0.max_field0,

outer1.min_field1,
outer1.max_field1,

outer2.min_field2,
outer2.max_field2,

...

from
(
    select middle0.nonile_field0,
    min(middle0.field0) as min_field0,
    max(middle0.field0) as max_field0
    from
    (
        select inner0.field0,
        ntile(9) over (order by inner0.field0) as nonile_field0
        from
        (
            select repo.field0
            from my_table as repo
            where repo.field0 >= 0 and repo.field != ""
        ) as inner0
    ) as middle0
    group by middle0.nonile_field0
) as outer0

inner join
(
    select middle1.nonile_field1,
    min(middle1.field1) as min_field1,
    max(middle1.field1) as max_field1
    from
    (
        select inner1.field1,
        ntile(9) over (order by inner1.field1) as nonile_field1
        from
        (
            select repo.field1
            from my_table as repo
            where repo.field1 >= 0 and repo.field1 != ""
        ) as inner1
    ) as middle1
    group by middle1.nonile_field1
) as outer1
on outer0.nonile_field0 = outer1.nonile_field1

...

order by nonile
```

The output of the query will look like this (for example):

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| nonile | min_field0   | max_field0   | min_field1   | max_field1   |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|      1 | 0            | 0.27         | 0.09892169   | 0.2505006    |
|      2 | 0.27         | 0.33         | 0.2505006    | 0.2900893    |
|      3 | 0.33         | 0.37         | 0.2900893    | 0.3300329    |
|      4 | 0.37         | 0.41         | 0.3300329    | 0.3687165    |
|      5 | 0.41         | 0.46         | 0.3687165    | 0.4048001    |
|      6 | 0.46         | 0.5          | 0.4048001    | 0.4399964    |
|      7 | 0.5          | 0.55         | 0.4399964    | 0.4828034    |
|      8 | 0.55         | 0.62         | 0.4828034    | 0.5445772    |
|      9 | 0.62         | 0.98         | 0.5445772    | 0.7808363    |
+--------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Note that I've manually edited the field and table names so that they are generic for this post, but the code should still be correct.